# fwupd service fails to start

Tags: 20.10, firmware, fwupd

For a while now I have a problem with fwupd.

Initially I noticed an error message every time I open Ubuntu Software.
The error reads "Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.fwupd: Failed to activate service...". See image below for more details.

[Error message on Ubuntu Software v3.38.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBJOe.png)

When I try to start fwupd via terminal using the following command:

```
$ sudo service fwupd start
```

I get the following message:

```
Job for fwupd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status fwupd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So if I run "systemctl status fwupd.service" I get this:

```
######@HP-ENVY-Notebook:~$ systemctl status fwupd.service 
● fwupd.service - Firmware update daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fwupd.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-02-15 19:35:23 GMT; 7s ago
       Docs: https://fwupd.org/
    Process: 6237 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/fwupd/fwupd (code=exited, status=127)
   Main PID: 6237 (code=exited, status=127)

Feb 15 19:35:23 HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1]: Starting Firmware update daemon...
Feb 15 19:35:23 HP-ENVY-Notebook fwupd[6237]: /usr/libexec/fwupd/fwupd: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgusb.so.2: undefined symbol: libusb_get_parent
Feb 15 19:35:23 HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Feb 15 19:35:23 HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 15 19:35:23 HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1]: Failed to start Firmware update daemon.
```

As you can see I am using a HP laptop (bad decision), which has an Intel Core i5 and is running Ubuntu 20.10 groovy. (I can provide more information if needed.)

If I run "sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt upgrade" it shows that all packages are up-to-date.

Any ideas please?

Comment: It seems that this bug report might be related. It says this should have been fixed in v1.4.0 of fwupd. Ubuntu 20.10 provides v1.4.5, so... maybe it's not the exact same bug...

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text include the text in the question.

Comment: @alci which bug report is that? I have seen some similar bug reports, but none of them seems to have any solution for me. From what I understand the problem relates to _libgusb_ or _libusb_, but I am not sure how to safely reinstall these without damaging my system. Any help/suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: The fwupd service seems to work now!

After I made some new updates the problem seems to be fixed. I guess it was just a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Im getting same error message, but i can start it by running the command `sudo service fwupd start`. but I will have to do it after every reboot.